# One-way repeated measure ANOVA with LMER and AOV

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I am trying to do an **One-way repeated measure ANOVA**.

My data is: 42 respondents answering 5 questions in 4 different categories, i.e. everyone answered 20 questions, for each of the 4 categoreis the same 5 questions.

Example: evaluating a risk for a financial product in category 1, category 2, category 3, category 4.

I have tried to the One-way repeated measure ANOVA with the lmer-function and the aov-function, but got completely different results.

My variables:

- dependent_variable = risk
- indepentent_variable = seq (counting the 42 respondents)
- category (as condition)

Approach for lmer:

```
anova_risk <- lmer(risk~ category + (1|seq), data = survey_anova_detail)

Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
category 6.3512  2.1171     3   123  4.5367 0.004724 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Approach for aov:

```
aov_risk <- aov(risk~ category + Error(seq/category), data=survey_anova_detail)

Error: seq
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1  0.608   0.608               

Error: seq:category
         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
category  3  2.953  0.9843

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
category    3    4.6   1.526   0.688  0.561
Residuals 160  354.9   2.218
```

Shouldn't the F-Vaue an p-Value be approximately the same? I am not sure, if the codes are right or am I interpreting the results wrongly? Besides, I don't need a longitudinal analysis of the category.

Thanks for every help!